# Angular 11, ''router-outlet' is not a known element:'

Tags: angular, routes

I have already searched posts with similar scenarios as mine, all they did is add RouterModule in the Module on which the second router-outlet sits(layout.module in my case),  I just coudn't figured out what is wrong with my routing.

**app.component.html**

```html
     <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**app.module**

```js
    import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
    import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
    import { BrowserAnimationsModule } from '@angular/platform-browser/animations';
    import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
    import { FormsModule, ReactiveFormsModule } from '@angular/forms';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';

    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [
        AppComponent,
        PageNotFoundComponent,
      ],
      imports: [
        BrowserModule,
        LayoutModule,
        AppRoutingModule,
        BrowserAnimationsModule,
        ReactiveFormsModule,
        FormsModule,
        RouterModule
      ],
      bootstrap: [AppComponent]
    })
    export class AppModule { }
```

**app-routing.module**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { Routes, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    import { CourierModule } from './features/courier/courier.module';
    import { CustomerModule } from './features/customer/customer.module';
    import { LoginModule } from './features/login/login.module';
    import { ShopOwnerModule } from './features/shop-owner/shop-owner.module';
    import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout/layout.component';
    import { PageNotFoundComponent } from './page-not-found/page-not-found.component';
    
    const routes: Routes = [
      { path: '', redirectTo: '/login', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'login', loadChildren: () => LoginModule },
      {
        path: '',
        component: LayoutComponent,
        children: [
          {path: 'shop-owner', loadChildren: () => ShopOwnerModule},
          {path: 'courier', loadChildren: () => CourierModule},
          {path: 'customer', loadChildren: () => CustomerModule}
        ]
      },
      { path: '**', component: PageNotFoundComponent }
    ];
    
    @NgModule({
      imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
      exports: [RouterModule]
    })
    export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**layout.component.html**

```html
    <p>layout worksxxx!</p>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

**layout.module**

```js
    import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
    import { CommonModule } from '@angular/common';
    import { LayoutComponent } from './layout/layout.component';
    import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
    
    @NgModule({
      declarations: [LayoutComponent],
      imports: [
        RouterModule,
        CommonModule
      ],
      exports: [LayoutComponent]
    })
    export class LayoutModule { }
```

I can't figured what causes the "router-outlet' is not a known element" error on layout.html, can anyone shed some light on me.

Comment: try removing `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in `layout.component.html`. i think that part is not needed since you have it in `app.component.html`

Comment: @LahiruMirihagoda, what i am trying to achieve is to have layout component render, other compoents, and have like a menus at the top, so its super necessary in my design!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Import Wrong Layout Module in AppModule,

In AppModule File, Line 6;

```
import { LayoutModule } from '@angular/cdk/layout';
```

Import LayoutModule from your Module not @angular/cdk/layout.

Answer (score 0):

hmm.. double check where router oulet is defined, I think you should import `RouterModule` into your `app.module.ts`

```
import { RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
```

Add `RouterModule` into your `imports []`

**like this:**

```
 imports: [    RouterModule,  ]
```

Comment: I have already done this, still have "'router-outlet' is not a known element:"

Answer (score 0):

I think you should put your `<router-outlet></router-outlet>` in the `app.component.html` and use `activitedRoute` or `router.navigate` on other component